# Append Font Awesome Icon to <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I would like to append an Font Awesome Icon to a new created `li`

On click I'm creating a new `li`, which needs two icons on it.

HTML:

```
<ul class="todo" id="todo">
</ul>
```

JS:

```
function addItemToDo() {

    var list = document.getElementById('todo');

    var itemName = document.getElementById('item').value;
    var task = document.createElement('li');

    task.appendChild(document.createTextNode(itemName));
    list.appendChild(task);

    /* ADD ICONS */
    task.className += "fa fa-trash-o fa-3x";
    task.className += "fa fa-check-circle-o fa-3x";
}
```

The new element gets created, the icons are 'bugged' somehow.
I also tried to append them with the Unicode, which did not work for me either.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem. Also, why the jQuery tag if you aren't using any jQuery?

Comment: Why are you making two `task.className` calls (i.e. to the same element)? The resulting class will be `fa fa-trash-o fa-3xfa fa-check-circle-o fa-3x`.

Comment: well you can not have two font awesome icons on the same element....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't add the font awesome classes to the `li` element,
Instead you need to create something like this:

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>can be used</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>as bullets</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-square"></i>in lists</li>
</ul>
```

*from font awesome examples page

create an '`i`' element and set ITS class to the font awesome glyph you want.